# String matches all 26 A to Z characters

Tags: java, regex, string

How can I check if a string contains all 26 characters from a to z?
I am trying this but it does not give the solution, as I want to print yes if the string has all 26 chars otherwise no.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class CompleteString {

    static int MyFun(String s)
    { 
        if(! s.matches(".*[^a-z].*") )
            System.out.println("YES");
        else
            System.out.println("NO");
        return 0 ;

    }
    public static void main(String args[] ) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T = in.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<=T;i++)
            {
                String s1 = in.nextLine();
                int result = MyFun( s1);
                System.out.println(result);

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This check doesn't even need any regex

Comment: ohh.. m new in programming. please help.

Comment: The `.*` are screwing you up.  You're saying match any character. Then match any character thats not a-z, then match any character.  You just want `^[^a-z]*$`.

Comment: now compiler says..illegal start of expression :-/

Comment: See [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/oX1pE9/1) for some explanation, @ChrisThompson allready gave the right answer :-)

Comment: not getting.. I want to take string as input. if string contains all 26 charcter then i want to print yes otherwise no. can anyone please help me to correct in my code or provide me new code.????

Comment: look at my code.. even after changing my if statement , i am getting same output. tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: `s.matches("(?i)[a-z]{1,}")` will match 1 or more letters, a-z, and will ignore case; allow uppercase with the `(?i)` flag.

Comment: This question has multiple problems, but it's not an exact duplicate. OP wants to check if string contains each letter from A to Z. I'll vote to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ensure that all 26 letters of the alphabet appear in the string, and not just some combination with repeated letters, using regex seems like a poor way to do it. A simple loop through the alphabet would be my approach. e.g.:

```
boolean containsWholeAlphabet(String input){
    boolean matches = true;
    for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++){
        if (!input.toLowerCase().contains(String.valueOf(ch))){
            matches = false;
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Comment: not working Generic Jon

Comment: There seems to be no `break;` after `matches = false;`. Put it there and it should work.

Comment: Inserting `break;` will not change the program. It would only make it return faster.

Comment: Yep, you are right. The other issue with the code is that `input.toLowercase()` should be done definitely before the loop and assigned to a local variable that later would be used inside the loop.

Comment: Confession time: I wrote this off the top of my head and didn't test it. Turns out that `toLowercase` should be `toLowerCase` and I missed a closing parenthesis.

Comment: @Jagger Those are both optimizations that I would make, if I was writing production code instead of quickly hashing out an answer on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways.

1) Writing a regular expression
    `(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)...(?=.*z).*`

This regular expression checks for one occurrence of each alphabet.

2) Writing a for loop for each character match.

```
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    if (str.indexOf(c) == -1) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u're looking only for a-z letters its pretty simple

```
char[] chars = "souRce".toCharArray();
for(char c : chars){
   if(!(c >= 'a' && c <='z')){
          // fail on first occurence itself to avoid remaining characters
          System.out.println("source contains other letters");
          break;
      }
 }
```